# Django URL without trailing slash not working

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, url, django-1.9

[image: Updated Page not found (404)]

This is a silly problem. I just created a project and have been trying to figure out this problem.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),
    url(r'^about$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="about.html")),
    url(r'^contact$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="contact.html"), name="contact"),
    url(r'^test$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="test_start"), name="test_start"),
    url(r'^test/sample$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="test_start"), name="test_start"),
]
```

is included into

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('frontend.urls'))
]
```

When I go to `localhost:8000/about`, I get redirected to `localhost:8000/about/` and there I get 404 Not Found.

UPDATE: I added more URLs into my URLconf.

UPDATE 2: I meant to not include trailing slashes. My apologies.

UPDATE 3: I opened the same URL in Firefox and the URL works like I intend. Could this be a problem with redirection and browser cache?

Comment: Your config looks fine. From which browser/Rest Client are you testing?

Comment: I am using templates from another project. I'll take a look at the templates to see if I can figure anything out. And the browser is Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

First, I found out that Chrome automatically adds trailing slash at the end of the URL

[Trailing URL Slashes in Django](https://dev.to/learndjango/trailing-url-slashes-in-django-4bf#:%7E:text=Among%20Django%27s%20many%20built%2Din,URLs%20that%20would%20otherwise%20404.)

So if you don't have a trailing slash on your URLS, a 404 redirect will show if you're using Chrome, but not if, say, Firefox.

Then from the comment of **knbk** from here,

[How Django adds trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45282296/how-django-adds-trailing-slash)

I made sure I had the CommonMiddleware class in *setting.py* and added '`APPEND_SLASH = False`'

Then, cleared Chrome's cache, and problem solved!

Comment: helpfull!!..Thanks

Comment: this is actually explained why the setting never worked because it's not he server problem it's a browser default settings!

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable the `append_slash` setting ?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash

using this may help to make it more explicit and is recommended throughout the django tutorials

```
url(r'^about/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="about.html")),
```

EDIT:

Deactivate the `APPEND_SLASH` settings (False) and use

```
url(r'^about$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="about.html")),
```

Comment: Sorry, the slashes in the end of the patterns are typos. I actually want to remove the trailing slashes.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the `$` from your regex, this indicates the end of line

```
url(r'^about', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="about.html")),
```

You could also just include a slash to your regex, since Django has a [`APPEND_SLASH`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#append-slash) setting which will issue a redirect

```
url(r'^about/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="about.html")),
```

> if the request URL does not match any of the patterns in the URLconf and it doesn’t end in a slash, an HTTP redirect is issued to the same URL with a slash appended.

Answer (score -1):

Change your url pattern for "about" to:

```
url(r'^about/?$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="about.html")),
```

Without the `/?`, the regex `^about$` matches a string containing exactly the word "about".

Comment: Sadly, for some reason this does not help.