# How Django adds trailing slash

Tags: python, django

Working with the Django-powered project that would automatically put a trailing slash at the end. So:

```
foo.com/bar
```

would become a

```
foo.com/bar/
```

I [have read](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/middleware/#django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware) that there is a `CommonMiddleware` class which has an `APPEND_SLASH` attribute with which trailing slash can be controlled. My project import `CommonMiddleware` indeed:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
)
```

However `APPEND_SLASH` is never set anywhere. And the project keeps adding trailing slash.

---

**Question:** does `APPEND_SLASH` get set to `True` by default if you import `CommonMiddleware`? Are there any ways to control the trailing slash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will compile a full answer. It has 2 aspects:

1) If you import `CommonMiddleware` into your project - it would use its `APPEND_SLASH` attribute (which is `True` [by default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-APPEND_SLASH)).

2) Keep track of your urls file (if it is something like `^foo.com/bar/$`).

And don't forget to clear the cache if you change `CommonMiddleware` or `APPEND_SLASH`(since browser will most likely cache it).

Comment: I deleted CommonMiddleware in settings.py, still get slash in the end, even if I write **localhost/name** I would get **localhost/name/**

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to set `APPEND_SLASH` in your django settings module.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-APPEND_SLASH

Comment: Well it says, that default value is `True`. However I have removed `CommonMiddleware` from the project completely, and the trailing slash would still be added.

Comment: @Oleg Clear your browser cache. CommonMiddleware returns a permanent redirect.

Comment: Maybe you have another middleware adding it? You could try to remove all middlewares except `CommonMiddleware` and set `APPEND_SLASH` to `False` and see if it behaves as expected.

Comment: For example if one of the other middlewares you have inherits from `CommonMiddleware` it could be it that is adding the `/`.

Comment: @knbk You were right, after clearing the cache - redirect has gone.